# Application of van kampen - regarding induced isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology

I seem to be stuck on this particular exercise:

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be path-connected, and let $D^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a 3-ball with boundary sphere $S^2$ such that $D^3\cap X=S^2$. Show that the inclusion map $i: X \rightarrow X\cup D^3$ induces an isomorphism $i_*: \pi_1 (X,x_0)\rightarrow \pi _1(X\cup D^3,x_0)$ for any $x_0 \in X$. 
(Hint: apply van Kampen's theorem with the interior of $D^3$ as one of the open sets of the covering.)

Anyone out there with a bright idea?

Comment: what did you try ?? please share your thought with us...

Comment: Well i'm confused for several reasons. First of all - We need a cover of $X\cup D^3$ consisting of path-connected open sets and with each intersection of open set being path-connected. But $D^3\cap X=S^2$ so $int(D^3)\cap X= \emptyset$. My question to this is - is it ok to have an empty set as intersection, since an empty set is trivially path-connected. Second - How do I even give meaning to an isomorphism defined on $\pi_1 (X,x_0)$ when X is a closed set?

Answer (score 1):

1.) cf. Hatcher's book, p. 43: Every open set of the union has to contain the basepoint. In particular the intersection must not be empty.
URL: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf

2.) You can try it like this:

Let $U$ and $V$ be 
$$U = int(D^3) = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^3:||x||<1\} \mbox{ and } V=X\cup\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3:\frac{1}{2}<||x||\le 1\right\}.$$

Then 
$$U\cap V= \left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3:\frac{1}{2}<||x||<1\right\}.$$

By deformation retraction we have the following:
$$\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3:\frac{1}{2}<||x||\le 1\right\}\simeq \{x\in\mathbb{R}^3:||x||= 1\} =S^2$$
$$U\cap V=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3:\frac{1}{2}<||x||<1\right\}\simeq\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3:||x||=\frac{3}{4}\right\}\cong S^2$$
$$U = int(D^3) \simeq pt.$$

By the first line we conclude $V = X\cup\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3:\frac{1}{2}<||x||\le 1\right\} \simeq X\cup S^2 = X,$ because $X\cap D^3 = S^2$.

So the fundamental groups are
$$\pi_1(U\cap V)=\pi_1(S^2)=0$$
$$\pi_1(U) = \pi_1(pt.) = 0$$
$$\pi_1(V) = \pi_1(X).$$

The inclusion maps $U\cap V\hookrightarrow U$ and $U\cap V\hookrightarrow V$ induce trivial homomorphisms, because $\pi_1(U\cap V)=0$. So the normal subgroup of Seifert-van Kampen is trivial.

By Seifert-van Kampen we now have
$$ \pi_1(X\cup D^3) = \pi_1(U)\ast \pi_1(V) = 0\ast \pi_1(X) = \pi_1(X).$$

Q.E.D.